# Redirecting to another page in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

I have a basic `navbar` in my web page. When I click any `nav-items` I am trying to redirect the user to another page.

I have route set up for that but when I click that `nav-item` I am not able to redirect it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="collapse animated fadeInLeft" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="">Home</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="{{ Route('staticController@contact') }}">link</a> </ul>
    </div>
```

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('/','homeScreenController@index');
Route::get('/contact','staticController@contact');
```

If I try to do this,I get a error message that on my homepage itself saying,

```
Route [staticController@contact] not defined.
```

but I have already defined it.

and when I do this error doesn't come but it will not take me to contact page.

```
<li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="{{ ('staticController@contact') }}">link</a> </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('/contact') }}">link</a>
```

Comment: no error but no able to navigate to that page. Nothing happens

Comment: if I type `/contact` in url above , it goes to that page but not when I click

Comment: Please check, whether you're missing any tag or something else. Also check the html content by inspecting in browser.

Comment: when I hover on the link in the console it show it show navigate to /contact but when i click i shows /#

Comment: thanks for your help. There was a problem with my `js` file. I resolved it now. Thanks bud :)

Comment: Great!! Best of luck and happy coding. :)